# Chrome DevTools remote debugger shows colors differently

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am using chrome remote debugging tool based on this [tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/).

However, when I open a page on my device and view it in the debugger window, on my developer machine it shows the color somehow in a monotone way, like this:

[image]

For example, here the food is yellow and red but it shows the screen in DevTool window blue.

**How can I force it to show real colors? I cannot find any option in the settings.**

Maybe a related setting would be `Emulate vision deficiencies` in Rendering options:

[image: Emulate vision deficiencies]

When I play with option it shows different color tones but still not the real colors as I see in my device.

Comment: Reported here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1193394

Comment: Claimed to be fixed here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1189626

Comment: The problem still is there, even in their recent update Version 90.0.4430.72